# Iterate over all pairs (or triples) of consecutive elements with wrap-around

Tags: python

I have found many similar questions, but none of them with the wrap-around aspect.

I'm working on some code where I have a lot of lists where one item is connected to the following, or even the following and the previous item. Thus I get this pattern a lot, though sometimes I only use `current_item` and `following_item`, so without `previous_item`.

```py
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    current_item = my_list[i]
    following_item = my_list[(i + 1) % len(my_list)]
    previous_item = my_list[(i - 1) % len(my_list)]
```

Or alternatively, using `enumerate`:

```py
for i, current_item in enumerate(my_list):
    following_item = my_list[(i + 1) % len(my_list)]
    previous_item = my_list[(i - 1) % len(my_list)]
```

Both of which don't seem very 'pythonic' to me. Is there a nice pythonic way to do this? I've seen some answers to related questions where they do something like `zip(my_list, my_list[1:])`, but this doesn't wrap-around, and I also don't see a nice way to extend it to include the previous item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are looking for something like this:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for previous, current, following in zip([mylist[-1]] + mylist[:-1], mylist, mylist[1:] + [mylist[0]]):
    print(previous, current, following)
```

Here I simply used zip and list concatenation.

Comment: I wonder if it can be done even more concisely, but this does seem to do exactly what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem really boils down to adding the last element to the `prev` and the first one to the `next`. So you can just *"expand"* the list:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

new_l = [l[-1]] + l + [l[0]]
for prev, cur, next_i in zip(new_l, l, new_l[2:]):
    print(prev, cur, next_i)
```

Will give:

```
6 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6
5 6 1
```

This uses the fact that [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) stops according to the shortest iterable (which is the original `l`).

---

If, for some reason, you need to do this repeatedly on the same list, you can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to create an endless *wrap-around* iterator on the list:

```py
from itertools import cycle

for prev, cur, next in zip(cycle(new_l[:-2]), cycle(l), cycle(new_l[2:])):
    print(prev, cur, next)
```

Which will give:

```
6 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6
5 6 1
6 1 2
1 2 3
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you're looking for, but you might be wanting [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle). You can try something like this:

```
from itertools import cycle

lst = [1, 2, 3]

pool = cycle(lst)

previous = lst[-1]
current = next(pool)
following = next(pool)

print(previous, current, following)
>>> 3 1 2

while True:
    previous, current = current, following
    following = next(pool)
    
    break

print(previous, current, following)
>>> 1 2 3
```

Now, calling `next(pool)` will always give the next item in the list in a cycle, so hopefully that's the wrap around you're talking about.

The print statements are of course just to show what's going on with the list but as you can see, 1 cycle of the `while` loop will move each variable up one in the list.